# armazenar id do registo php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Boas pessoal, o meu objetivo é armazenar o id do registo que foi inserido na base de dados

```
$sql = "insert into pacientes (Nome, idade, dataNascimento, estadoCivil, nacionalidade, naturalidade, morada, telemovel, niss, nif, situacaoEconomica, trabalho, salario, outros, possuiFamilia, familiarProximo, parentesco, moradaFamiliar, contactoFamiliar, inscritoCentroSaude, qual, medicoFamilia, contacto, sns, grupoSanguineo, antecendentesClinicos, informacoesAcompanhamento) values ('$nome', '$idade', '$dataNascimento', '$estadoCivil', '$nacionalidade', '$naturalidade', '$morada', '$telemovel', '$niss', '$nif', '$situacaoEconomica', '$trabalho', '$salario', '$outros', '$possuiFamilia', '$familiarProximo', '$parentesco', '$moradaFamiliar', '$contactoFamiliar', '$inseridoCentroSaude', '$qual', '$medicoFamilia', '$contacto', '$sns', '$grupoSanguineo', '$antecendentesClinicos', '$informacoesAcompanhamento')";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql);
    $numero = mysqli_affected_rows($ligacao);
    if($numero==1)
    {
        $codigo = mysqli_insert_id($ligacao);
        echo "<span style='position:absolute; margin-top:600px; margin-left:400px; color:green;'>Inserido com sucesso. </span>";

}
```

Eu aqui consigo armazenar o id deste registo atraves do mysqli_insert_id-`$codigo = mysqli_insert_id($ligacao);`

O meu problema é que eu a seguir queria armazenar o id do registo mas de outra query e já não posso usar a mesma forma porque o meu objetivo seria inserir numa outra tabela o id de registo de uma query e o id de registo de outra query

```
    $result = count($_POST["agregado"]);
    $agregado=$_POST["agregado"];
    $t=0;
    $m = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<$result; $i=$i+4)
    {

   $p=$i+1;
   $e=$p+1;
   $b = $e+1;

    $sql_1="insert into agregado (nome, parentesco, idade, bi) value('$agregado[$i]', '$agregado[$p]', '$agregado[$e]', '$agregado[$b]')";
    $resultado_1 = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_1);
    $sql_2 = "insert into utenteagregado (id_agregado, id_utente)  values ('1', '$codigo')";
    $resultado_2 = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_2);
}

    mysqli_close($ligacao);
}
```

Resumindo nesta linha  `$sql_2 = "insert into utenteagregado (id_agregado, id_utente)  values ('1', '$codigo')";` onde tem o numero 1 eu quero inserir o id desta query `$sql_1="insert into agregado (nome, parentesco, idade, bi) value('$agregado[$i]', '$agregado[$p]', '$agregado[$e]', '$agregado[$b]')";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa a função last_insert_id()

No teu caso:

```
$sql_1="insert into agregado (nome, parentesco, idade, bi) value('$agregado[$i]', '$agregado[$p]', '$agregado[$e]', '$agregado[$b]')";
$resultado_1 = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_1);
$sql_2 = "insert into utenteagregado (id_agregado, id_utente)  values (last_insert_id(), '$codigo')";
$resultado_2 = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_2);
```

Um comentário importante na [documentação oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function%5Flast-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

e

> LAST_INSERT_ID() returns
>   only automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT values. If you store an
>   explicit value other than NULL or 0, it does not affect the value
>   returned by LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: Obrigado, acho que já está a funcionar